# How to get mercurial to notice files added into subdirectories? (hg st, hg add)

Tags: mercurial, subdirectory

If I add a new file into my project's root, it appears with a `?` status in `hg st`, and gets added with `hg add`.

However, if I add a new file into a subdirectory, it doesn't appear in `hg st` at all, and only gets added if I explicitly add the file (not even if I add the file's containing directory).

How can I get mercurial to notice files in subdirectories, in a similar way to how subversion notices them?

Thanks

Comment: Does this happen for any subdirectory (i.e. independent of it's name) or just for specific ones?

Comment: Please post a specific example illustrating the problem, starting from an `hg init` like the example in my answer/guess.

Comment: Does `hg status --all` give you a listing for the file?

Answer (score 15):

Well, plain `hg add` without any extra arguments adds files in sub-directories as well, it basically adds all files with status unknown to be tracked.

However, if you specify a simple mask, it only operates on your current working directory (ie. the working directory of the hg command, not the working directory associated with the repository), so if you're currently situated in the sub-directory, it will add those files, if you're in the root directory, it will add those files instead.

In other words, this:

```
hg add test*
```

Only operates on files in the directory you're currently situated.

You can override that behavior by specifying a mask that tells hg to operate on sub-directories:

```
hg add **/test*
```

This says "add all files that match 'test*' in the current directory and all sub-directories.

If you remove one of the asterixes, you only operate on sub-directories of the current working directory.

It would help if you posted what specific commands you executed, and the output, if any, and the output of `hg st` before and after.

Comment: I'm not applying any mask. I just add a file in a subdir and do an `hg st`, and see no output (not even an unknown `?` status for the file). If I do the same thing in the root directory, I do see the file with an unknown status. It's worthwhile to mention the subdir isn't in ignored in the .hgignore

Comment: What is the name of the directory, and what is the name of the file, and can you post your .hgignore file, just in case?

Comment: Oh, and check @Mark Tolonen's answer here as well, it might be that that's your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Did you `hg init` in the subdirectory as well?  If so, don't.  Below illustrates the issue:

```
C:\>hg init project
C:\>cd project
C:\project>hg init sub
C:\project>echo >file1
C:\project>echo >sub\file2
C:\project>hg st
? file1
```

Delete the subfolder's `.hg` directory to fix it:

```
C:\project>rd /s/q sub\.hg
C:\project>hg st
? file1
? sub\file2
```

Unlike Subversion, Mercurial only uses an `.hg` directory at the root of a project.

Comment: Thanks Mark but no, I didn't `hg init` any subdir, and there's no `.hg` directories other than in my root. Any other idea?

Comment: Only idea is to post a complete example of the commands leading up to the problem.  Do you have an .hgignore at all?  Maybe something is accidently matching. What happens if, in a brand new directory, you `hg init`, make create a file, create a subdir, create a file in the subdir, and `hg status`?  That should show both files.